# Import CSV file into MySQL without using load data infile

Tags: mysql, csv

I have recently switched web hosting providers and the new provider does not allow 'load data  infile' commands in MySQL.  However, I have many CSV files that update tables in a database weekly using that command.  What is the best way to import into MySQL without the typical load data option?  I tried mysqlimport, but that seems to fail since the data isn't in SQL format, its just standard CSV data.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Script to read the CSV, then build the `INSERT` statements yourself?

Comment: @user2895995 - Have you tried `load data LOCAL infile`? There's also a `mysqlimport` command in Linux that performs the same functionality, otherwise you'll have to do what jimbobmcgee recommended and create inserts.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the local option, but the 'load' command in general is blocked.  How can you specify which table to import into using mysqlimport?

Comment: Just found out that mysqlimport is also blocked by the web host.  I guess I may be making the inserts from the file.

Comment: MySQL CSV Storage Engine might help you out here

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Convert the CSV to the MySQL CSV dump format
- Upload the file to the MySQL server or to the shared hosting file system
- Use one of the following commands to import it:

  - mysqladmin:

    ```
    mysqladmin create db1
    mysql db1 < dump.csv
    ```
  - mysql:

    ```
    mysql> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db1;
    mysql> USE db1;
    mysql> source dump.csv
    ```

**References**

- [MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 7.4.2 Reloading SQL-Format Backups](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reloading-sql-format-dumps.html)
- [Text::CSV::Auto - Comprehensive and automatic loading, processing, and analysis of CSV files. - metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV::Auto)
- [MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 8.4.3 Dumping Data in Delimited-Text Format with mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html)
- [Restore data from a tab delimited file to MySQL - Electric Toolbox](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/restore-data-tab-delimited-file-mysql/)
- [Using mysqldump to save data to CSV files - Electric Toolbox](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-mysqldump-to-save-data-to-csv-files/)
- [Mysqldump in CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040816/mysqldump-in-csv-format)