# What is the best way to dump MySQL table data to csv and convert character encoding?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv, unix

I have a table with about 200 columns. I need to take a dump of the daily transaction data for ETL purposes. Its a MySQL DB. I tried that with Python both using pandas dataframe as well as basic write to CSV file method. I even tried to look for the same functionality using shell script. I saw one such for oracle Database using sqlplus. Following are my python codes with the two approaches:

Using Pandas:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import pandas as pd

host = ""
user = ''
pass_ = ''
db = ''

query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1'

conn = mdb.connect(host=host,
                   user=user, passwd=pass_,
                   db=db)

df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)
df.to_csv('resume_bank.csv', sep=',')
```

Using basic python file write:

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
import datetime

currentDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()

host = ""
user = ''
pass_ = ''
db = ''
table = ''

con = MySQLdb.connect(user=user, passwd=pass_, host=host, db=db, charset='utf8')
cursor = con.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM %s;" % table
cursor.execute(query)

with open('Data_on_%s.csv' % currentDate, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        writer.writerow(row)

print('Done')
```

The table has about 300,000 records. It's taking too much time with both the python codes.

Also, there's an issue with encoding here. The DB resultset has some latin-1 characters for which I'm getting some errors like : `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\x96' in position 1078: ordinal not in range(128).`

I need to save the CSV in Unicode format. Can you please help me with the best approach to perform this task.

A Unix based or Python based solution will work for me. This script needs to be run daily to dump daily data.

Comment: Hope this helps-https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that just leveraging [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html). For example:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE...
INTO OUTFILE 'your_file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

if you need to schedule your query put such a query into a file (e.g., csv_dump.sql) anche create a cron task like this one

```
00 00 * * * mysql -h your_host -u user -ppassword < /foo/bar/csv_dump.sql
```

Comment: Instead of running SQL query, I need to run a script to do this task so that I can use a scheduler. This will help me get a good control over the scripts because the script will do other tasks too like creating directories.

Comment: You can schedule the query as a script! @amulya349 take a look at the edit ; )

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The SQL will work only if my MYSQL server is running on the same server as the script. But, my MYSQL DB is a cloud-managed one like of AWS. There this SQL won't do the work. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Hope This Helps-https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#csv

Comment: @floatingpurr Worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good news! Feel free to accept the answer if it solved :)

Answer (score 2):

For strings this will use the default character encoding which happens to be ASCII, and this fails when you have non-ASCII characters. You want unicode instead of str.

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
f = open('Data_on_%s.csv' % currentDate, 'w')
myFile = csv.writer(f)
myFile.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in rows])
fp.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It solved my problem. But its a bit slow with 300k records. Any idea how to speed it up?

Comment: Yes go for pandas library

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysqldump` for this task. ([Source for command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14356942/1392490))

```
mysqldump -u username -p --tab  -T/path/to/directory dbname table_name --fields-terminated-by=','
```

The arguments are as follows:

- `-u username` for the username
- `-p` to indicate that a password should be used
- `-ppassword` to give the password via command line
- `--tab` Produce tab-separated data files

For mor command line switches see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

To run it on a regular basis, create a cron task like written in the other answers.