# While exporting mysql table into .xls file using php server gets slowdown and exported file gets crashed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, export-to-excel

I have a table in mysql database with 20 columns and 1000000 rows.i have tried to export it in .xls file using phpexcel but it slows down the system and the exported file is corrupted.please help me to export it using php.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$Qry= $con -> query("SELECT * FROM `table_1`");
$fn="excel_report";
$rowCount = 1;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount,'COL 1')->getStyle('A'.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($headerColor);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount,'COL 2')->getStyle('B'.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($headerColor);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount,'COL 3')->getStyle('C'.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($headerColor);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount,'COL 4')->getStyle('D'.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($headerColor);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount,'COL 5')->getStyle('E'.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($headerColor);
while($row=$Qry->fetch_array()){
$rowCount++;
$col_1=$row['col_1'];
$col_2=$row['col_2'];
$col_3=$row['col_3'];
$col_4=$row['col_4'];
$col_5=$row['col_5'];
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $col_1)->getStyle('A'.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($allBorder);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $col_2)->getStyle('B'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $col_3)->getStyle('C'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $col_4)->getStyle('D'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $col_5)->getStyle('E'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
}
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$cellIterator = $sheet->getRowIterator()->current()->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells( true );
foreach( $cellIterator as $cell ) {
$sheet->getColumnDimension( $cell->getColumn() )->setAutoSize( true );
$sheet->getStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
$sheet->getStyle()->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
}
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
```

Comment: show what have you done so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysqldump in CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040816/mysqldump-in-csv-format)

Comment: i think this is to big, you should do this via CLI there a have no max requesttime. But this will slowdown your pc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code to convert a MySQL query to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv)

Comment: code has been updated above, please check @BunkerBoy