# Export amazon mysql database to an excel sheet

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

I have an ec2-instance on which mysql database is there and now there are multiple tables have huge values which i want to export into an excel sheet into my local system or even some place at S3 will also work , how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysqldump in CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040816/mysqldump-in-csv-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to export CSV files from RDS Mysql  and without getting  `Access denied for user '<databasename>'@'%' (using password: YES)` is doing the following command:

```
mysql -u username -p --database=dbname --host=rdshostname --port=rdsport --batch -e "select * from yourtable" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > yourlocalfilename.csv
```

The secret is in this part:
`--batch -e "select * from yourtable" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > yourlocalfilename.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Given that you installed your own MySQL instance on an EC2 node, you should have full access to MySQL's abilities.  I don't see any reason why you can't just do a `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
INTO OUTFILE 'output.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Once you have the CSV file, you may transfer it to a box running Excel, and use the Excel import wizard to bring in the data.

**Edit:**

Based on your comments below, it might be the case that you need to carefully select an output path and location to which MySQL and your user have permissions to write.

Comment: Not working , it is saying  Access denied for user '<databasename>'@'%' (using password:                                                                                                  YES)

Comment: If you can't even connect to your MySQL instance on EC2, then you have an entirely different problem.  And this has nothing to do with how to export your data from MySQL.  If you can't connect to MySQL, basically you won't be able to do anything.

Comment: But i am able to login in to my instance and access my database and view all my tables

Comment: Then maybe the location is the problem.  See my updated answer.

Comment: does output.csv should already be existing or it will automatically create one

Comment: It should automatically create one AFAIK, assuming you can get around these permissions problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185810/discussion-between-vatsal-rahul-and-tim-biegeleisen).